# Start activity for limited time on android

Tags: android, android-activity, controls

I'm developing an app in android that is based on cleverly sequencing executions of another app's activity, controlling the interval between each execution.

The problem is that once the other activity takes over it naturally keeps running at the foreground, preventing my app from killing it and start it again after the interval has passed.

1. I tried to start the other activity from a **Service** in my app, hoping that the service is able to start a new instance of that activity of the other app in place of the previous instance.
2. I tried using `dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN,KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK))` from my app's activity/service when the other app is running.

Neither worked.

What are my possibilities to reclaim the control for the parent activity?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to start the other activity from a Service in my app, hoping
>   that the service is able to start a new instance of that activity of
>   the other app in place of the previous instance.

Have you tried `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` with the `Intent` when starting `Activty` from `Service`?